# Correcting header translations / signatures in standard units

Tags: unit-testing, delphi

Embarcadero sometimes translates headers incorrectly.

There are multiple examples but i would like to point out the `Winapi.D2D1.pas` unit, which includes the translation of `directwrite.h`.

In the `IDWriteFactory` interface we have a function called [CreateGdiCompatibleTextLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368192%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), whose current declaration is incorrect.

What we have in Winapi.D2D1.pas is:

```
function CreateGdiCompatibleTextLayout(var _string: WCHAR; stringLength: Cardinal;
  var textFormat: IDWriteTextFormat; layoutWidth: Single; layoutHeight: Single;
  pixelsPerDip: Single; var transform: TDwriteMatrix; useGdiNatural: BOOL;
  out textLayout: IDWriteTextLayout): HResult; stdcall;
```

If you check out the MSDN link above you'll see the correct translation should be:

```
function CreateGdiCompatibleTextLayout(_string: PWCHAR; stringLength: Cardinal;
  const textFormat: IDWriteTextFormat; layoutWidth: Single; layoutHeight: Single;
  pixelsPerDip: Single; transform: PDwriteMatrix; useGdiNatural: BOOL;
  out textLayout: IDWriteTextLayout): HResult; stdcall;
```

As i said this is just a small piece and you'll find incorrect translations all over the Winapi units.

And this brings me to my initial question.

> So how to correct false translations?

So far i've come across 3 solutions.

### **Option 1 - Copying the unit**

Copy the unit you would like to replace a function in and place it either within your projects dir or in the searchpath of RAD.

The IDE will now use this unit instead of the one in your install dir. `(E.g. C:\...\sources\rtl\win\Winapi.D2D1.pas).`

Although seems like a quick and easy fix it has a problem. As other units are compiled with Winapi.D2D1.pas you will run into conflicts. For example when you try and compile a Firemonkey Application, which uses said unit.

You could recompile the system units but it seems like a sloppy solution.

### **Option 2 - Redeclaring the interface**

Within your project you could declare the interface again including your fix.

```
 IDWriteFactory = interface(IUnknown)
['{B859EE5A-D838-4B5B-A2E8-1ADC7D93DB48}']

...

function CreateGdiCompatibleTextLayout(_string: PWCHAR; stringLength: Cardinal;
  const textFormat: IDWriteTextFormat; layoutWidth: Single; layoutHeight: Single;
  pixelsPerDip: Single; transform: PDwriteMatrix; useGdiNatural: BOOL;
  out textLayout: IDWriteTextLayout): HResult; stdcall;

...

end;
```

### **Option 3 - Using other translations**

Embarcadero isn't the only translater of those headers. Other software developers release their translations and post them online.

So we could use them.
In this secific example you'll find translations for the DirectWrite and Direct2D here:

https://github.com/CMCHTPC/DelphiDX12

and here:

http://www.delphipraxis.net/179042-header-uebersetzung-directx-11-1-und-direct2d-1-1-a.html

---

I would like to know how fellow software developers handle those situations and what their approch of correcting is.

Of course it would be nice if Embarcadero could fix those translations. But after some research it seems they don't really care and mark them as "as designed" ([Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=112581))

Thanks for your time reading!

Comment: Submit bug reports and if they really are wrong they should be fixed. I know they fixed a bunch that I reported as wrong. This is pretty much an opinion based question. FWIW, I use option 2.

Comment: Having said that, the "as designed" on the report is especially egregious and shows how broken Embarcadero's quality system is. Once the face of it, the developers there have managed to set up enough layers of fake incompetent QA so that they don't get to see bug reports. And instead they get inexperienced devs to triage bugs and they simply don't know enough to get it right. No real dev could regard that as "as designed".

Comment: I guess you are complaining about, for example the _string. I would have thought that this was only a problem if you are translating a piece of code from say C, where effectively _string is a pointer in one piece of code and an instance in the other. Otherwise I would have thought the Delphi version easier to implement, which is, I guess, why they do it. Or am I missing something more subtle? (To clarify, what I mean is that the var modifier will cause the pointer to be passed anyway).

Comment: The original translation is indeed wrong and yours is correct.. `_string` is indeed a `PWCHAR` and not `var ... WCHAR`, and `textFormat` is not `var`. I would copy and rename the unit, to avoid the conflicts you encountered. I generally make it clear, in the unit name, that this is a copy.

Comment: @Dsm: `var` means that actually a pointer is passed, but it makes using the function harder. Arrays and strings should never be translated as `var` parameters. The big bummer is declaring the interface variable with `var`, though. That simply passes the **wrong** pointer. The translator did either not know, or forgot, that while in C, an interface is passed through a pointer, while in Delphi, it is a reference type that does not require you to pass it with a pointer.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Yes, I see. I did know this, but I guess like the translator, I forgot. :-(